# Unable to compile angular component in handsontable cell

Tags: angular, handsontable

Really stuck in a problem, I’m using handsontable with angular2. And in handsontable I’m using cell renderes to populate cells and that cell contains an angular component.

But the problem is that cell is not compiling in angular scope

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile the component you want to display in the cell and add the component's html to the cell in a custom renderer. Here's an example:

```ts
import { Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef,
  OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-table-cell',
  template: '<b (click)="counter++">Counter: {{counter}}, data: {{data.id}}<b>'
})
export class MyTableCellComponent {
  counter = 0;
  data: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-table',
  template: `
    <hot-table [options]="currentOptions">
    </hot-table>
    <div #templateContainer
        [hidden]="true">
    </div>`,
})
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('templateContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    templateContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  options: ht.GridOptions;
  private cellComponentFactory: ComponentFactory<MyCellComponent>;
  private cellTemplateComponents: {[id: string]:
    ComponentRef<MyTableCellComponent>} = {};

  constructor(private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {};

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.options = { columns: [{
      renderer: this.rendererLinkCell.bind(this),
      data: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
    }]};
    this.cellComponentFactory = this.factoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(MyTableCellComponent);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    _.forOwn(this.cellTemplateComponents, (component) => {
      component.destroy();
    });
  }

  private rendererLinkCell(_instance: any, td: Element, _row: number,
      _col: number, _columnKey: string, data: any, _cellProperties) {
    let component = this.cellTemplateComponents[data.id];
    if (!component) {
      component = this.templateContainer
        .createComponent(this.cellComponentFactory);
      _.extend(component.instance, { data });
      component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.cellTemplateComponents[data.id] = component;
    }
    $(td).html(component.location.nativeElement);
  };
}
```

I haven't had time to test it, so let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Rene. let me check and get back to you