# angular 1 compile in angular 2

Tags: angular, handsontable

In angular 1 what we can do is

```
var elem = document.getElementById('#someid');
$compile(elem)($scope);
```

and this works like charm. But i'm unable to find equivalent of above in angular 2. I'm really stuck.

To give you overview, i m using a library handsontable which is a javascript library and adds different elements to dom. Now i have element out of angular scope which i now want to include in angular scope

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/39507831/6813271 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44921361/6813271.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can upgrade to Angular 4 which is most stable version and it have backward compatability.You can use  **ComponentFactoryResolver**  as an alternative for **$compile** in Angular 4

https://fromjami.com/2017/06/26/load-components-dynamically-at-runtime-in-angular-4/

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

In your case you can create a component with an html that you want to compile at runtime

Comment: thanks! but i have read this document. my problem is i have an element with me and i want to compile it

Comment: @AmitpalRawat put that html in a component and load it. It will compile on runtime

Comment: It will be compiled in compile time not runtime since we have to add it to entryComponents

Comment: @XAVI  .. okay to give you overview, i m using a library handsontable which is a javascript library and adds different elements to dom. Now i have element out of angular scope  which i now want to include in angular scope

Comment: @AmitpalRawat I would suggest please edit your question and add relevant information to the question like above.So you will get good solution and answers.And also there is no concept of scope in Angular JS2 like Angular 1.0.

Comment: @XAVI thanks !! i know there is no scope. but i just need to tell angular that hey look i have added something new can you please compile it